# Async running twice

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I got an async task that posts JSON data, the web service i post it to sends it as an email. I have a problem now the email is being sent twice. I already disabled the button and added the progress dialog while the task is on doInBackground. I cant seem find the error why it sends twice. In my logs it only returns the success once.

Here is the code of the async task

```
public class postEmail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
            String response;
            @Override

            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                pd.dismiss();
                if (response.contains("success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message successfully sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("success", "sent success");
                    clearEditText();
                    editSubject.requestFocus();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sending Failed. Kindly check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                super.onPostExecute(s);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyTheme);
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.setMessage("Sending...");
                pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
                pd.show();

                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                    Log.d("POST EMAIL", "SENDING");
                    String finalEmail = "qcqpsd.admin@stluke.com.ph";
                    String finalCcEmail = "nolascolee@gmail.com";
                    String postUrl = "http://qpsdev.stluke.com.ph/webservice/qpsSendEmail";
                    List<NameValuePair> post_email = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    post_email.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", finalEmail));
                    post_email.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", finalSubject));
                    post_email.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", finalMessage));
                    post_email.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender", finalSender));
                    post_email.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cc", finalCcEmail));
                    response = jsonParser.getJSONFromPostURL(postUrl, post_email);
                    Log.d("result", response);
                    return result = jsonParser.getJSONFromPostURL(postUrl, post_email);
            }


        }
```

And here is the code for the button:

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        getValue();
            if(isConnected)
            {
                finalizeString();
                new postEmail().execute();
            }
                else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check your connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = jsonParser.getJSONFromPostURL(postUrl, post_email);
                    Log.d("result", response);
                    return result=jsonParser.getJSONFromPostURL(postUrl,post_email);
```

in here you send the file twice,change the return part and don't call method again mate

Comment: Working properly now. Thanks a lot.